# How to close the sign-in tab after successful sign-in?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, botframework

I am using:

1. MS Bot framework's Node SDK (version 3.7)
2. AuthBot (using OAuth2)

I have coded it such that the magic number generated is automatically saved and the dialog session commences, as soon as the user has logged in via the MS-account.

My question is: is it possible to close the tab of the browser window once the sign-in is successful? I have tried searching this at various places, and have also tried the `windows.close()` method, but nothing works.

If not, is it possible to intercept the link (that it is about to open in the tab) and open a local HTML file (with the code: `<script> window.close() </script>`), post sign-in?

Here's the snippet of the code which generates the JSON response:

```
server.get('/api/OAuthCallback/',
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log('OAuthCallback');
    console.log(req);
    const address = JSON.parse(req.query.state);
    const magicCode = crypto.randomBytes(4).toString('hex');
    const messageData = { magicCode: magicCode, accessToken: req.user.accessToken, refreshToken: req.user.refreshToken, userId: address.user.id, name: req.user.displayName, email: req.user.preferred_username };
    magicNum = magicCode;

    var continueMsg = new builder.Message().address(address).text(JSON.stringify(messageData));
    console.log(continueMsg.toMessage());
    test_name = JSON.parse(req.user._raw).preferred_username.split("@")[0]
    bot.receive(continueMsg.toMessage());
    res.send('Sign-in successful');
  }
);
```