# Close window pop up after log in in node js

Tags: node.js, express, botframework

I am doing azure ad authentication in my node js bot.
in the last step it is showing a  pop windows with magic code.
I want to close that magic window pop up automatically after 5 sec.

this is code

```
res.send('Welcome ' + req.user.displayName + '! Please copy this number and paste it back to your chat so your authentication can complete: ' + magicCode);
```

this line send a window pop with magic code. iwant to close this window after 5 sec automatically.
my code

```
server.get('/api/OAuthCallback/',
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log('OAuthCallback');
    console.log(req);
    const address = JSON.parse(req.query.state);
    const magicCode = crypto.randomBytes(4).toString('hex');
    const messageData = { magicCode: magicCode, accessToken: req.user.accessToken, refreshToken: req.user.refreshToken, userId: address.user.id, name: req.user.displayName, email: req.user.preferred_username };
    magicNum = magicCode;

    var continueMsg = new builder.Message().address(address).text(JSON.stringify(messageData));
    console.log(continueMsg.toMessage());
    test_name = JSON.parse(req.user._raw).preferred_username.split("@")[0]
    bot.receive(continueMsg.toMessage());
    res.send('Sign-in successful');
  }
);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using `botauth` lib, if so, there should be a html page which you need to use to display `magic code`.

This html should contain a similar js script code like:

```
document.getElementById("magic_code").innerText = (window.location.hash || '').replace('#', '');
```

And you can add following code to close the window in 5 secs

```
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.close();
    }, 5000);
```

The similar code sample at https://github.com/CatalystCode/node-authbot. And all use the OAuth 2.0 process, which once user success signin the authenticate provider, it will redirect to your return url you configed in your server.

In your code, your auth return route simply send a string in browser. Also, you can render a HTML page to your user, however, you will face the issue

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

The same as the question you provide in comment.

Unfortunately, there are several question for this on SO:
[window.close() doesn't work - Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937212/window-close-doesnt-work-scripts-may-close-only-the-windows-that-were-opene)
[window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome/23679748), and currently no good solution for this.

Comment: there is no webpage for magic code. this is a pop up. there are two ways one is for web based authentication and another for desktop application , I am using desktop application auth, so there is no webpage for that, after filling  ADID and password it in one pop up. magic code displayed in another pop up

Comment: I think I mix up the authentication method you are using. As mentioned in original question you are using AAD, but what confusing me is that bot in node.js and expressjs both are web applications, so how you authenticate your user via desktop application auth?

Comment: yes I am using bot auth with node js.bot will be integrated with msteams. now when user sign in into bot it open a window pop up(not in browser) so the magic code comes on windows pop up.i wan to close that automatically.

Comment: @CPVerma, actually, I mean could you provide more details about how you integrate with AAD in your bot. Any code snippet, or post you follow, or library you are using.

Comment: i have same eproblem like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672670/how-to-close-the-sign-in-tab-after-successful-sign-in